# What is Skrill's policy on its use in BTC trading?

Tags: exchanges, trading

- Is [Skrill](http://www.skrill.com) tolerant of Bitcoin trade using its system?
- Does it have any kind of history of reversing transactions or suspending accounts involved in Bitcoin trading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 6.7 of the Skrill ToS bans sending payments that are "in connection with any money changing or transmitting business, including but not limited to bureaus de change or currency exchanges"

Bitcoin trade counts as currency exchange, so yeah.

Comment: Link to it and I'll accept!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. https://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=terms